# python.exe is not a valid win32 application

Tags: python, winapi, installation

I found several topics relating to this issue (when I try to run python.exe in command line, I get the subject error message), but none of the suggestions worked for me. I have installed and uninstalled around 5 times now. I wasn't getting this error earlier tonight after first installing, FWIW.

I am running Windows 7 64 bit. I realized that my first default 3.5.1 install was 32-bit so I uninstalled. Then I installed Windows x86-64 executable installer. I tried that twice. I switched to version 2.7.11 Windows x86-64 MSI installer. I still get this error. On the latest try (2.7.11), I ran Dependency Walker and got 3 errors:

> Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
>   Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
>   Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.

The first error is that python27.dll is missing. I found that in the System folder and copied it into the main folder of my install (C:\Python27) and then also tried the DLL folder. Still getting my same error. Pulling me hair out and it doesn't help that I am brand new to python in general! I am worried that the uninstalls haven't been scrubbing properly or I have otherwise messed this up.

Thanks and sorry!

Comment: Open a command prompt and type `where python.exe`. That will tell you, where the OS is looking for the executable, and may give a clue where to start diagnosing this issue. It's very likely that the uninstaller didn't clean up the *%PATH%* environment variable properly, and the system is still looking in the wrong place.

Comment: That was it! One of the uninstalls must have left a python.exe in another directory, so now the ActivePython install I just did seems to be working now! You are an absolute angel.